# How to specify output name for qt5_add_translation?

Tags: qt, cmake, translation, qt-linguist

I want to generate a plenty `*.qm` for plenty `*.ts` files for different languages using `qt5_add_translation`. All the `*.ts` files are named using `*.de_DE.ts`/`*.fr_FR.ts`/etc convention. But `qt5_add_translation` produce output, using only basename until first `.`, not the last one.

There is no possibility to pass options to `lrelease` using `qt5_add_translation(QM_FILES "${PROJECT_NAME}.de_DE.ts" OPTIONS -qm "${PROJECT_NAME}.de_DE.qm")` syntax.

Also setting `OUTPUT_NAME` property for source `*.ts` file is not working:

```
set_source_files_properties(
    "${PROJECT_NAME}.de_DE.ts" PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    OUTPUT_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}.de_DE.qm"
    )
```

Producing filename in the case is still `"${PROJECT_NAME}.qm"`, not `"${PROJECT_NAME}.de_DE.qm"`

How to override producing name for resulting `*.qm` file?

Surely I can make custom command and use it for my purposes, but I prefer to use ready `qt5_add_translation`.

#### EDIT:

Looking at `/usr/local/Qt-5.9.2/lib/cmake/Qt5LinguistTools/Qt5LinguistToolsMacros.cmake` I conclude, that there is no way to achieve desired using ready to use `qt5_add_translation`, because of using `get_filename_component(qm ${_abs_FILE} NAME_WE)` to get filename:

> NAME_WE   = File name without directory or longest extension

For my purposes there is need to use combination of `ABSOLUTE` (to get filename w/ full suffix), then to apply multiple times `EXT` in combination with `NAME_WE` to extract filename w/o shortest extension.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the below custom function `add_translation` to replace `qt5_add_translation`:

```
function(ADD_TRANSLATION _qm_files)
    foreach(_basename ${ARGN})
    set(qm "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_basename}.qm")
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${qm}"
        COMMAND "${Qt5_LRELEASE_EXECUTABLE}"
        ARGS -markuntranslated "Not translated!" -nounfinished -removeidentical -compress "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_basename}.ts" -qm "${qm}"
        DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_basename}.ts" VERBATIM
    )
    list(APPEND ${_qm_files} "${qm}")
    endforeach()
    set(${_qm_files} ${${_qm_files}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

It accepts basenames of `*.ts` files and produces list of resulting `*.qm` files: both in current source directory.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to Qt 5.9.4 or newer. The handling of .ts files with dots in the name has been fixed there, see also https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64317 .